# Minimal number of steps needed to turn all binary bits to one state

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

There is an array of M binary numbers and each of them is in state '0' or '1'. You can perform several steps in changing the state of the numbers and in each step you are allowed to change the state of exactly N sequential numbers. Given the numbers M, N and the array with the members of course, you are about to calculate the minimal number of steps needed to turn all the binary numbers into one state - 1 or 0.

---

If M = 6 and N = 3 and the array is 1 0 0 1 0 0, then the solution will be 2.
Explanation: We can flip them so they all be 1 in two steps: we flipped from index 2 to 4  and we transform the array to 111000, and then flip the last three (N) 0s to 1.

Comment: 1. Is this homework? 2. How large are M and N? (For instance, would an O(M 2^N) algorithm work?) 3. Your English is perfectly fine. I don't think this problem has a famous title.

Comment: Does the problem guarantee there is always a solution? For 1 0 1 and N = 3 for example there is no solution. Should the algorithm account for these cases or not?

Comment: You'll probably get more responses if you try the problem, put some code or pseudo-code in your question, and then ask for comments.

Comment: M and N are in the range of 1-100000 so bruteforcing won't work in any possible way. It's a dynamic-programming problem, and it should be solved as such.

Comment: @thebretness: If i had ANY possible idea, i wouldn't post here - i'd try it and see what i get. The problem is i don't know any possible way to solve this.
@Ivlad: You are right, there wouldn't be always a solution so the output will be -1 or smth.

Comment: Where is this question from? E.g. if it's from a contest, what level? (IOI/ICPC/USACO/easier?) If it's from a class or textbook, what class? :-)

Comment: It's from a class, and i don't know how to tell you which class - we are preparing for a contests with our professor (bulgaria).

Comment: I posted a full working C++ program. I'm sure it is correct according to my understanding of the question, but you may want to test it on harder examples and modify your question and my understanding. :-)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Search the web for Lights Out for a suitable title.

Comment: @IVlad: If 1 <= N < M, then there is a _unique_ solution. This can be proven using Linear Algebra.

Comment: @Moron: Consider N = 2 and 1 0 1 1, which has no solution either.

Comment: @IVlad: Oh, right. I must have made a mistake (most likely confused row rank with column rank). But if there is a solution, it must be unique, I think that part is correct. Shreevatsa's algorithm does both, either tell if there is no solution or give the unique solution. In any case, this problem can be solved using Linear Algebra, and does not require any dynamic programming.

Comment: @IVlad: Here is what I was thinking: For M > N, we can rewrite as the problem as the equation Ax = b, where A is Mx(M-N+1) matrix and b is our initial set. Each column of A corresponds to one operation. We can show that the columns are linearly independent. For square matrices this implies a unique solution, but our matrix isn't square. It implies that there is at most one solution (as we have more equations than variables). This is where I went wrong. So if there is a solution, it is unique, but there are cases (as you showed) where there need not be a solution.

Comment: That makes sense. A very nice solution, I wonder why the professor asked for a dynamic programming algorithm. Is there something we're missing? @VaioIsBorn: could you present the posted solution in class and tell us what your professor says please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I've understood the question correctly, a little bit of thought will convince you that even dynamic programming is not necessary — the solution is entirely trivial.

This is the question as I understand it: you are given an array a[1]..a[M] of 0s and 1s, and you are allowed operations of the form S<sub>k</sub>, where S<sub>k</sub> means to flip the N elements a[k],a[k+1],...a[k+N-1]. This is only defined for 1≤k≤M-N+1, clearly.

By performing a sequence of these operations S<sub>k</sub>, you want to reach either the state of all 0s, or all 1s. We'll solve for both separately, and take the smaller number. So suppose we want to make them all 0 (the other case, all 1s, is symmetric).

The **crucial idea** is that you would never want to perform any operation S<sub>k</sub> more than once (doing it twice is equivalent to not doing it at all), and that the order of operations does not matter. So the question is only to determine which subset of the operations you perform, and this is easy to determine. Look at a[1]. If it's 0, then you know you won't perform S<sub>1</sub>. Else, you know you must perform S<sub>1</sub> (as this is the only operation that will flip a[1]), so perform it — this will toggle all bits from a[1] to a[N]. Now look at a[2] (after this operation). Depending on whether it is 1 or 0, you know whether you will perform S<sub>2</sub> or not. And so on — you can determine how many operations (and which) to perform, in linear time.

**Edit:** Replaced pseudo-code with C++ code, since there's a C++ tag. Sorry for the ugly code; when in "contest mode" I revert to contest habits. :-)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int INF = 20000000;
#define FOR(i,n) for(int i=0,_n=n; i<_n; ++i)

int flips(int a[], int M, int N, int want) {
  int s[M]; FOR(i,M) s[i] = 0;
  int sum=0, ans=0;
  FOR(i,M) {
    s[i] = (a[i]+sum)%2 != want;
    sum += s[i] - (i>=N-1?s[i-N+1]:0);
    ans += s[i];
    if(i>M-N and s[i]!=0) return INF;
  }
  return ans;
}

int main() {
  int M = 6, N = 3;
  int a[] = {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0};
  printf("Need %d flips to 0 and and %d flips to 1\n",
         flips(a, M, N, 0), flips(a, M, N, 1));
}
```

Comment: Can you see the edited question again - i posted an example ? 
The solution looks too easy for me, this problem should be really hard (so they say).

Comment: Oh, I just realised that this algorithm isn't linear time because the "perform the flip" bit also takes linear time in N, so it becomes O(MN). You can get around this using a queue I believe (a queue of the position of the last flips within N of the current position).

Comment: @VaioIsBorn: I tested it on the example, and it finds 2 flips. Maybe they overestimated its hardness. :-) @Poita_: Look at the code, not the description — you can keep track of the flips in constant time each, by using a sliding window (that's the "sum" above).

Comment: @VaiolsBorn: If N < M, then I believe there is a _unique_ solution (of course, not flipping the same set twice), so not sure what the talk about 'minimum' required number is.

Comment: @VaiolsBorn: Above comment was to make all 0. Of course if we have an option of making all 0 or 1, then there are two solutions and we just pick the smaller one. Also, this algorithm in fact proves the uniqueness to make all 0 (similarly all 1s can be proven too).

Answer (score 3):

I coded up the algorithm that ShreevatsaR proposed, but with the added queue improvement to get it to real linear time in M.

```
int solve(vector<bool> bits, int N)
{
  queue<int> flips;
  int moves = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < bits.size(); ++i)
  {
    if (!flips.empty() && flips.front() <= i - N)
      flips.pop();

    if ((bits[i] ^ (flips.size() % 2 == 0)) == 1)
    {
      if (i > bits.size() - N)
        return -1; // IMPOSSIBLE

      moves++;
      flips.push(i);
    } 
  }

  return moves;
}
```

Just run that on the original and the inverted original and take the minimum (if they aren't -1). If both are -1 then it is impossible.

Note that I have neither compiled or tested that code, but it should work.

Comment: Is there a reason for picking vector<bool>? Most people advise against it and I have trouble figuring out what actually happens when I see it used. Especially with operator^(bool, bool) as used in the if.

Comment: (Deleted earlier comment.) I actually had the linear-time improvement, but this is nicer (at least, more C++-ish) code. +1.